# Pasar datos de una variable de un archivo a otro

Tags: javascript, nodejs, filesystem, module.exports

Tengo un archivo en node js, este archivo genera una variable `globalPage` que contiene un objeto el cual quiero pasar de un archivo a otro, cuando se haga una petición post, el problema es que no se como hacerlo, ya he intentado con file system y exportando la variable como modulo pero aun no funciona/ la función que genera la variable es esta:

```js
async function startApp() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://www.rappi.com.co/')
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        isMobile: false
    })
    await page.click('#header > div > div.header-content-right.not-logged > div.header-user-dropdown.ng-star-inserted > app-user-drop-down > div > button', {
        button: 'left'
    })
    globalPage = page
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar cómo deseas usar tu función? A simple vista (si bien falta usar `try / catch` dentro de tu función `startApp`), se ve todo bien (semánticamente hablando). Lo que hace falta es ver cómo pretendes usar esa función, es decir ¿cómo la llamas o ejecutas? Es necesario ver todo el contexto. ¿Entiendes que es una función `async` y por lo tanto la variable `globalPage` tomará el valor de `page` en un momento futuro incierto? Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Espero poder ayudarte :D

La función debe retornar el resultado:

```
async function startApp() {
    ...
    await page.click('#header > div > div.header-content-right.not-logged > div.header-user-dropdown.ng-star-inserted > app-user-drop-down > div > button', {
    button: 'left'
    })

    return page
}
```

luego exportas el resultado que devuelve la función al llamarla:

```
module.exports = startApp()
```

luego llamas el resultado desde otro archivo. Por ejemplo:

```
   const resultado = require('./startApp.js')

   async function mostrar_resultado(){
       console.log(await resultado)
   }


   mostrar_resultado()
```

Recuerda que estás trabando con promesas, por lo tanto, la función donde llames el resultado debe ser `aysnc` y esperar el resultado con `await`